# What can be said about functions that have Fourier coefficients $c_n=0$ after a certain $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $e_n$ be an orthogonal basis of $L^2[a,b]$. Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be $L^1[a,b]$ such that all its Fourier coefficients in $e_n$ exist. The Fourier coefficients of $f$ in that basis are

$$c_n=\int_a^b f(x)e_n(x) \, dx$$

Suppose there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $c_n=0$. How does that translate on the function $f$ ? What does it mean for $f$ ? Something about its regularity maybe ?

Maybe this question is too broad, because I am not saying anything about $e_n$, so in case we need a more precise statement, here is what interests me: $a=0,b=1$ and $e_n$ are the shifted Legendre polynomials.

Comment: In the case where $e_n$ is a polynomial basis, then the statement should be exactly equivalent to $f$ being polynomial.

Comment: If I am not mistaken this means that your function is in a finite subspace of $L^2[a,b]$ generated by ${e_1,e_2,...,e_N}$

Comment: It just implies your function is a finite linear combination of your basis elements, so all the properties you would expect would be strictly derived from the properties of $e_i$.

Comment: $f$ is only $L^1$, not necessarily $L^2$, do your comments still apply ? In the $L^2$ case, it is obvious, but I do not see it in the $L^1$ case.

Comment: Take $f-P$; all Fourier coefficients are zero, hence $f=P$